# Adding microsoft world web app to a website - or previewing documents online.

Tags: php, ms-word, powerpoint

Hi all you lovely stack peeps... heres hoping you can help me with a small conundrum.

A web system I am developing needs to provide users with the ability to preview documents. I am looking into ways of generating Jpgs of the first few pages of documents but that may not be possible on our server ATM.

Facebook seam to have recently gone very microsoft, one of the functions they have added is the preview option to "docs". This seams to use the world web app tool by microsoft.

I have googled arround and the only way to use this seams to be to embed things from a skydrive account. This won't suit my website (and I think we would break to terms if we tried) so I was wondering if there was some kind of API available. I havn't found one but I was wondering if anyone else had?

Alternatively what is the best solution for previewing Microsoft documents on-line?.. is there a library or tool kit available anywhere for doing this kind of thing? Is there an open office version of the world web app?

Cheers!

Chris

Comment: I know this is not a valid solution but maybe could be a bad-but-still-working solution: Convert your DOC into a PDF and show it to the user, this **may** be more possible, I think there are various library to convert from doc to pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question, you try to preview documents like pdf,ppt,doc etc within your web app?
If yes, you can try [google docs viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer/?pli=1)
You can have an iframe, with its src targeting to the google viewer. So, if your document is this: `http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf` you can preview it like:

`<iframe src='https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsamplepdf.com%2Fsample.pdf&embedded=true'width='400'></iframe>​`

Edit:
Here's a fiddle of how it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/7ueuU/

Edit 2: 
Here's a list of supported files: http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1738646

Comment: You Sir are a legend in your own time. If your ever in Bangor I'll buy you a beer (or glass of milk... whatever your particular poison is...) Awesome solution!!